# How can I move archived emails to my inbox from a bulk-selected search result

Tags: gmail, gmail-labels, gmail-search

With the intention of moving certain groups back after seeing the through the clutter, I archived all unread emails that had a user label (`label:unread has:userlabels`).

But now, when I bulk-select the results of my search for the labels/folders whose contents I want to move back to my inbox, the "Move to Inbox" button is nowhere to be found!

How can I move these groups of archived emails back to my inbox?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out, gmail will not allow you to move emails to the inbox that are already IN the inbox. So, if some of your selections ARE already in the inbox, you'll be presented with this uncanny sight, wherein the "Move to" option has replaced "Move to Inbox": [image: ribbon without "Move to Inbox" icon]

This "Move To" menu does not include "Inbox" in it's list of destinations. Therefore, if you are trying to bulk select the results of a search, or the contents of a folder (aka label) in an attempt to send those items back to your inbox, you must filter-out the all emails which are ALREADY IN the inbox.

To do this, simply add `-label:inbox` to the end of your search. And be sure to include the `-` before the word `label`, to signify "minus". After that, you'll be greeted by this beauty: [image: ribbon with "Move to Inbox" icon]